# Django (1.10.4) Migrations not applying datetime field changes(copies) in runpython

Tags: django, django-migrations

Changes in runpython are never applied for datetimefield.

I'm adding a new `datetimefield` on a model with an optional default of timezone.now()

model

```
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

migrations

```
operations = [
    migrations.RunPython(add_expense_date),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='expense',
        name='date',
        field=models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now),
        preserve_default=False,
    ),]
```

I wrote a `migrations.RunPython` method that copies the values of another field `_created_at` to the new field `date` for existing fields.

```
    def add_expense_date(apps, schema_editor):
        Expense = apps.get_model("accounting", "Expense")
        db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
        for expense in Expense.objects.using(db_alias).all():
            expense.date = expense._created_at
            expense.save()
```

Problem is, it always applies the defaut value and never applies the changes in the `runpython` calls. The `runpython` methods do get called however.
When I make the field nullable, it defaults all the values to null instead of the changes in the runpython call

Comment: What is `expense._created_at`?

Comment: It's an existing field on the model. A `datetimefield(auto_add_now=True)`